# Slash added automaticaly before bucket name with fstab and gcsfuse

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse, fstab

I use gcsfuse to mount bucket in google compute engine.

For this i use this syntax in my fstab :

```
my_bucket /my_bucket gcsfuse rw,uid=1001,gid=1002
```

But gcsfuse process is launch like this :

```
/usr/bin/gcsfuse --foreground -o rw --uid 1001 --gid 1002 /my_bucket /my_bucket
```

With "/" before "my_bucket", the mount do not work.

It's run in Ubuntu 16

Why fstab add this "/" automaticaly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. Must not have a bucket name like folder name in root path.

For this, i have rename my folder.

Comment: wow.  I never would have guessed that.  Saved me.  I was stuck for a while trying to figure it out.  Thanks.